# How to move un-pushed commits from one (local) branch to another in git?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I would like to move my local commit, not yet pushed to remote, to another branch.

I am supposed to follow this workflow. We just started with this practice, so kind of forgot. We have this JIRA & Bit-Bucket. We have to create a branch from JIRA item. Then I checkout this branch locally, work on this and commit (push) to it, and make a pull request to the code reviewer, then it gets merged to the respective branch and upwards to the master.

I forgot to create the branch for the JIRA item. Instead, I worked and committed to my local branch say 4.10BR. I did 3 separate commits (with respect to these 3 separate JIRA items).

My git log says...
On branch release/4.10
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/release/4.10' by 3 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Now, I would create a branch individually for these 3 items in (through) Jira-BitBucket, check these branches out, and "move" my commits to these branches (say b1, b2, and b3), and then push these branches.

Since I am still a learner in git, I do not have how to progress on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common workflow mistake, one which I have made dozens of times over the past decade.  The usual way I deal with is to do the following:

Create the new actual bona-fide branch which you should have created in the first place:

```
# from release/4.10
git branch feature/some_name
```

Now there is a branch `feature/some_name` created which contains your single commit of work.  The only remaining problem is the `release/4.10` branch, which now also contains an unwanted commit.  Given that you have *not* yet pushed the release branch, we can try doing a hard reset on that branch to remove this commit:

```
# from release/4.0, again
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Now you have your feature branch, and the release branch is in the state in which it would have been had you followed the correct workflow from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new branch from your current branch with command `git checkout -b 'name-of-branch'`. This keeps your code with 3 commits not pushed in the new branch. If you already created the branch, you can make the merge between the current branch to another branch with `git merge 'other-branch'`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to move your changes to an existing branch and/or you have many commits in the wrong branch, try the following. In my case, I committed to master when I meant to commit to develop, so it would look like this:

```
git checkout develop
git merge master
git checkout master
git reset --hard [HASH]
```

where [HASH] is the commit hash before your unwanted modifications, you could also use `HEAD~n` instead of [HASH], n being the number of unwanted commits.

If your branch doesn't exist, simply create it with `git checkout -b branchname`, then merge and reset.